No page transition when a button is pressed
The page does not transition when the button is pressed." I want to transition to "/user/profile".　Both isFirstSignIn and isAnonymous are false and the current path is "/". Can you please tell me the cause of this problem?
go_router.dart
final routerProvider = Provider((ref) => GoRouter(
      initialLocation: "/",
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/signin',
          builder: (context, state) => const AuthScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
            path: '/user/register',
            builder: (context, state) => const RegisterUserScreen()),
        GoRoute(
            path: '/user/profile',
            builder: (context, state) => const UserProfileScreen())
      ],
      redirect: (context, state) async {
        final isAnonymous = ref.read(authUsecaseProvider).isAnonymous;
        final signedInUser = ref.read(authUsecaseProvider).currentUser;
        if (signedInUser == null) {
          return state.matchedLocation == '/signin' ? null : '/signin';
        }
        final isFirstSignIn =
            await ref.read(userStatusUseCaseProvider).isFirstSignIn();
        if (isFirstSignIn && !isAnonymous) {
          return '/user/register';
        }
        if (isAnonymous) {
          return '/';
        }
        return null;
      },
    ));

home_screen.dart
class HomeScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //ref.read(authUsecaseProvider).signOut();
          GoRouter.of(context).go('/user/profile');
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


The problem lies in the "redirect". I comment your code written inside "redirect" function and it's working fine. The "redirect" function will call every time you try to navigate within your app. So, your conditions will check every time.
